# Converting serially reading multiple files to reading them in parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading, file

Following code in Java reads multiple files one after another **serially** and **it works well** till here. (The files are JSON and at this step they are stored in a String/Buffer without parsing.)

```
for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < numberOfFiles; fileIndex++) {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Files/file" + fileIndex + ".json"));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            String contentJSON = sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

How to read those files **in parallel** by using `Threads` ?

*I could not match Multithreading to above code and every time got errors.*

Comment: Please show what you tried and the errors you got.

Comment: @tgdavies , trust me! :-) ... I tested different approaches but after each time it didn't work, I deleted it as I believed it's not useable.

Comment: Before increasing the complexity of your code by an order of magnitude, ask yourself WHY you think you need to do this.

Comment: @JimGarrison , The files finally should be read in parallel. I wanted to create a serially reading approach to know how to read JSON file as a string, and then convert serial approach to parallel ... (I do know how did I increase the complexity of the code WITHOUT any reason ... )

Comment: Without seeing what you tried, we can't know what it is that you don't yet understand about threads in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tested this code directly (as I don't have a bunch of files to read), but the basic idea would be to do something like...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        try {
            int numberOfFiles = 10;
            ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
            List<ReadWorker> workers = new ArrayList<>(numberOfFiles);
            for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < numberOfFiles; fileIndex++) {
                workers.add(new ReadWorker(fileIndex));
            }
            List<Future<String>> results = service.invokeAll(workers);
            for (Future<String> result : results) {
                try {
                    String value = result.get();
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public class ReadWorker implements Callable<String> {

        private int fileIndex;

        public ReadWorker(int fileIndex) {
            this.fileIndex = fileIndex;
        }

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Files/file" + fileIndex + ".json"))) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = br.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This will basically execute a series of `Callable`s and wait for them all to complete, at which time, you can then read the results (or errors)

See the [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) trail for more details

## Tested and verified version...

So, I dumped a series of files into a the `Files` folder at the root of my working directory, modified the above example to list all the files in that directory and read them....

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {

        File files[] = new File("Files").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                return pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".svg");
            }
        });

        try {
            int numberOfFiles = files.length;
            ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
            List<ReadWorker> workers = new ArrayList<>(numberOfFiles);
            for (File file : files) {
                workers.add(new ReadWorker(file));
            }
            System.out.println("Execute...");
            List<Future<String>> results = service.invokeAll(workers);
            System.out.println("Results...");
            for (Future<String> result : results) {
                try {
                    String value = result.get();
                    System.out.println(value);
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            service.shutdownNow();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public class ReadWorker implements Callable<String> {

        private File file;

        public ReadWorker(File file) {
            this.file = file;
        }

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Reading " + file);
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = br.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And this works just fine and I have no issue.

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: Files\file0.json` is a localised issue you are going to have to solve.  Does `file0.json` actually exist?  Does it exist in the `Files` directory?  Is the `Files` directory in the root of the working directory when the program is executed?

None of these issues can be solved by us, as we don't have access to your environment

## Test #3

I then renamed all the files in my `Files` directory to `file{x}.json` using...

```
File files[] = new File("Files").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".svg");
    }
});

for (int index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
    File source = files[index];
    File target = new File(source.getParent(), "file" + index + ".json");
    source.renameTo(target);
}
```

And the modified the example slightly to include a `File#exists` report...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        try {
            int numberOfFiles = 10;
            ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
            List<ReadWorker> workers = new ArrayList<>(numberOfFiles);
            for (int index = 0; index < numberOfFiles; index++) {
                workers.add(new ReadWorker(index));
            }
            System.out.println("Execute...");
            List<Future<String>> results = service.invokeAll(workers);
            System.out.println("Results...");
            for (Future<String> result : results) {
                try {
                    String value = result.get();
                    System.out.println(value);
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            service.shutdownNow();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public class ReadWorker implements Callable<String> {

        private int fileIndex;

        public ReadWorker(int fileIndex) {
            this.fileIndex = fileIndex;
        }

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Reading " + fileIndex);
            File file = new File("Files/file" + fileIndex + ".json");
            System.out.println("File " + fileIndex + " exists = " + file.exists());
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = br.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
                return sb.toString();
            } finally {
                System.out.println("All done here");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Which prints

```
Execute...
Reading 8
Reading 1
Reading 2
Reading 4
Reading 6
Reading 9
Reading 3
Reading 7
Reading 0
Reading 5
File 8 exists = true
File 1 exists = true
File 5 exists = true
File 4 exists = true
File 9 exists = true
File 2 exists = true
File 0 exists = true
File 3 exists = true
File 7 exists = true
File 6 exists = true
All done here
All done here
All done here
All done here
All done here
All done here
All done here
All done here
All done here
All done here
Results...
// I won't bore you with the results, as it's a lot of pointless text
```

which all worked without issues

Comment: Thanks. I tested you code but I got error message again... I inserted the error message in the question.

Comment: That's not an error with the solution, but with the fact that where you think the files and where they actually are not inline with each other.  You need to verify that the from the working location can reach your files

Comment: But why in serial approach the files can be read? They are in the same location and directory.

Comment: Another thing: I called Class Test as follows in the Main class: `new Test(10 /*number of files*/);` where I added a parameter in Test class constructor : `public Test(int numberOfFiles)`

Comment: @Questioner I can't answer those questions for you, I don't have access to your environment nor am I able to replicate it.  I modified the example above so that it would list all the files in the `Files` directory and read them and it works fine for me, without issue.  I suspect that `File0.json` doesn't exist :P